# String Grouping in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, grouping

I'm working on [Cryptopals Challenge #6](http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6)

If the string is '11111222223333344444' and I want groups of 5, how do I group and compare the pairs.

For example, I want to group and compare '11111' and '22222', '33333' and '44444'. How could this be done?

I used this code and keep getting extra lines after the 4's...

```
>>> for i in range(0, int(len(string)/size)):
...     print(string[previous : previous + size])
...     print(string[previous + size : previous + size * 2])
...     previous += size * 2

11111
22222
33333
44444
```

What are other ways to do this?

Comment: compare ? what do you mean? they're different. You mean you can have 10 times `1` ?

Comment: Compare, in general, but specifically with this project, I need to take the average hamming distance of the string. So I need to take the hamming distance of the first and second strings, third and four strings, and so on, and then compute the average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `zip` idiom [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to group elements into groups of a known size.

```
s='11111222223333344444'
for i in zip(*[iter(s)]*5):
    print(i)
```

Outputs:

```
('1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
('2', '2', '2', '2', '2')
('3', '3', '3', '3', '3')
('4', '4', '4', '4', '4')
```

If you want them as a single string you can use `''.join`

```
for i in zip(*[iter(s)]*5):
    print(''.join(i))
```

Outputs:

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
```

Comment: How would I do this with a decoded base 64 string. For example, `base64.b64decode(string)` @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this. A classic implementation is via list comprehension:

```
chunks = [string[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(string), 5)]
```

Using itertools.zip_longest is my preference:

```
def chunk(seq, size):
    for ch in itertools.zip_longest(*([iter(seq)] * size)):
        if None in ch:
            ch = ch[:ch.index(None)]
        yield ''.join(ch)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def grouper(i, group_size):
    start = 0
    end = group_size
    while start < len(i):
        yield i[start:end]
        start = end
        end += group_size

groups = [i for i in grouper('11111222223333344444', 5)]

print(groups)
['11111', '22222', '33333', '44444']
```

Comment: There are a lot of extraneous copies here `while len(i[start:]): yield seq[start:start + group_size]; start += group_size` removes the need to keep track of a separate `end` variable.